# VB.net and jQuery scrollintoview plugin - scroll to a specific "input" element

Tags: jquery, .net

I am trying to use [scrollintoview jQuery plugin](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html) on a vb.net webpage and unfortunately, being fairly new at jQuery I am running into a problem.

I have a form that is pretty long with the submit button at the bottom. Validations are done in the code behind when the user clicks submit.

In my validate() sub,
I keep the ID of the control in error (say txtFirstName) in a variable ControlInErrorID
    controlInErrorID = txtFirstName.ClientID

I then attempt to scroll to the last control in error using a script manager:

```
If controlInErrorID <> String.Empty Then
    Dim csname1 As [String] = "ShowControlInErrorScript"
    Dim cstype As Type = Me.[GetType]()

    ' Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class. 
    Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript

    ' Check to see if the startup script is already registered. 
    If Not cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1) Then
        Dim cstext1 As New StringBuilder()
        cstext1.Append("<script type=text/javascript>")
        cstext1.Append("$(document).ready(function () {")
        cstext1.Append("    $(""#" + controlInErrorID + """).scrollintoview({")
        cstext1.Append("        duration: 5000,")
        cstext1.Append("        direction: ""vertical"",")
        cstext1.Append("        complete: function() {")
        'cstext1.Append("// highlight the element so user's focus gets where it needs to be")
        cstext1.Append("    }")
        cstext1.Append("});})")

        cstext1.Append("</script>")
        cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1.ToString())
    End If
End If
```

Trouble is, when run this, I have no errors, but nothing happens. 
Any idea please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you encounter an error, you are only registering the script, not executing it. I think you will need to reload the page for the javascript code to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code it seems that things should work... Some suggestions you could do to profile this problem you're having:

1. **Try to simplify your script for testing**

   Instead of using this script that uses `scrollintoview()` plugin, you can try and write a super simple script, that just displays an `alert` box displaying control ID. If it displays on postback, then there must be something wrong with either jQuery or the plugin loading...
2. **Use tools like Firebug**

   I highly recommend you use tools like Firebug (Firefox plugin) or at least Google Chrome's development tools that offer similar experience. Check:

   - whether jQuery has been loaded (likely in the `HEAD` section)
   - whether `scrollintoview` plugin has been loaded **after** jQuery library
   - whether this particular script has been added to your page at the bottom (just before closing `FORM` tag)
3. **Check whether `scrollintoview` actually works**

   You didn't provide any jQuery version information because I haven't tested this plugin with latest versions but I suppose it should still work regardless. But just to make sure, you can always test whether particular plugin actually works. All you have to do is open developer tools' *Console* (either in Firebug or Chrome's tools) and try executing:

   ```
   $("#someControlID").scrollintoview();
   ```

   If plugin is correctly loaded this should scroll that particular control into view (so make sure it's not in view already, because this particular plugin doesn't do anything when something is already in view).

   If this does nothing, you can also write this line:

   ```
   $.fn.scrollintoview
   ```

   And it should return *function()*. If it doesn't then this plugin hasn't been loaded as expected and you'll have to profile that.

Comment: 1. I used a shorter script:
`    cstext1.Append("$(document).ready(function(){$('#" + controlInErrorID + "').css('display','inline-block').css('border','3px solid green');});")`

That works so I know jQuery is loaded properly.


2. Using the Chrome Dev Tools console, under Network, I can see jquery-1.7.1 and jquery.scrollintoview are loaded. I can also see that the script has been  added before the `</form>`


3.jQuery-1.7.1; oddly enough, typing `jQuery` in the console still returns `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`. Replacing `.css()` by `.scrollintoview()` still does nothing :(

Comment: Based on your comment it seems you're having problems with jQuery. Dig on that. Check what was loaded as jQuery? If anything.

Comment: Indeed, it seems like I am having issues with jQuery as I am able to use some functions but not others. I tried using the core method ScrollTop instead of the ScrollIntoView plug-in and that did not work either. Thanks for  your tips, I'm going to keep troubleshooting my jQuery!